# in Angular 7 firebase data fetching with map module error "property rate does not exist of type {}"

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular7

my method for database fetching with one condition about rating.

```
favoriteBooks: Observable<any>;
geFavoriteBooks() 
{
    this.favoriteBooks = this.db.list('/books').valueChanges().map(
    books => 
        {
           const topRatedBook =<any> books.filter(item => item.rate > 4.0);
           return topRatedBook;
        })
    return this.favoriteBooks;
}
```

books is my firebase database,
topRatedBook is to get list of books which are having rating more than 4.
\\
error is:
property rate does not exist of type {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```ts
favoriteBooks: Observable<any>;
geFavoriteBooks() 
{
    return this.db.list('/books').valueChanges().pipe(map(
    books => 
        {
           const topRatedBook =<any> books.filter((item: any) => item.rate > 4.0);
           return topRatedBook;
        }
    ));
}
```

Because you want to map the results of the valueChanges-Observable and not the Observable itself. But remember that you return an Observable so you still have to display it like this:

```html
<div *ngFor='let top of (topRanked |async)'>
  {{top.name}}
</div
```

Comment: `import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';`